# Main.storyboard does not load

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to iOS and I'm making some exercises I'm stuck at the begining. I'd like to use standard Main.storyBoard which looks like this:
[image]

And the AppDelegate.m file looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
//    CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
//    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
//    
//    self.controler = [[ViewController alloc] init];
//    
//    self.window.rootViewController = self.controler;
//    
//    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    // Set root view controller and make windows visible
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];



    return YES;
}
```

And ViewControler if it will be usefull:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property UIView *viewM;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void) loadView
{
    CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    self.viewM = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: bounds];
    self.view = self.viewM;

}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"AHAHH DOTKNIETO EKRANU");
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 200, 50)];

    //SET TEXT FOR THIS LABEL

    label.text = @"TEXTTTTTT";
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Everytime I run this sample it loads me View which is white instead of the image above. What's not right with it? I'm using Xcode 5.1.1 version.

Comment: The title of the question says `Main.storyboard` but you've put this `storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"` as opposed to `storyboardWithName:@"Main"`

Comment: Sorry. I've corrected this mistake but still no progress. Xcode loads me ViewController class which is not declared to be loaded. What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the project - General page you should see a setting for "Main Interface".

Remove all the code in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` except `return YES;` and make sure this is set to `Main`.

[image]

Comment: I've done as you've writen here but still Xcode loads me view from ViewController class. How is it possible if I haven't created instance of this class?

Comment: @DKM oh... why are you replacing the view in viewDidLoad? Remove that code... `self.viewM = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: bounds];
    self.view = self.viewM;`

Comment: This is taking your storyboard view and throwing it away and replacing it with a new view.

Comment: I've deleted this and I have this message: "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
"

Comment: @DKM did you set the Main interface?

Comment: Sorry for this question but how to do this?

Comment: @DKM read my answer, this explains how to set the "Main Interface".

Comment: Yes, I've done it and nothing has changed. I've created new project and nothing happens

Comment: What do you mean "Nothing happens"? In the new project nothing happens? What did you select when you created the new project? Which template did you choose?

Comment: @DKM I'd recommend reading through a beginners tutorial about iOS development.

Comment: If you're using storyboards, your `didFinishLaunching` method should just `return YES;`. You don't want _anything_ else in there.

Comment: Ok. Let me I explain what I've done: I've followed tutorial on CodeSchool.com and there theacher showed to declare View in ViewController class like create UIView and set background color and in Appdelegate steps to setUp new UIControllerView. After that I've followed another tutorial and there guy shows how to use MainBoard. And this is how it has mixed up and this is why I've asked question. Now I've created new Project and everything is working fine. I've no idea why it has crashed.